# Why is Neon not used as a coolant for gas cooled nuclear reactors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, nuclear-engineering

What is the reason that Neon is not considered as good coolant for gas cooled reactors? I haven't found any research nor experiment with Neon in this field. As I checked out Neon has small neutron cross section area and is chemically inert. The next two isotopes are stable and the closest unstable isotope has a half life of 37s (don't know if it is considered high or low). 
The thermal conductivity and thermal capacity is similar to Carbon dioxide which is considered as a good coolant for gas cooled reactors.

Comment: Some information [here](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:7263485).

Comment: FWIW, Ne-23 decays to Na-23 (the usual stable isotope of sodium) via $\beta^-$ emission, with decay energy 4.375809MeV.

Comment: a cylinder of 5 nines neon was going for $17,000 in the late 80s.

Comment: @PN 2Ring Does that mean all the Ne-23 would just decay to Na-23 if used as reactor coolant?

Comment: Yes, any neon-22 that gets converted to neon-23 by absorbing a neutron will quickly decay to sodium-23. As you said, the halflife is around 37 seconds, so 99.9% of a sample of Ne-23 decays in around 6 minutes. The beta radiation it emits is fairly energetic: when it hits metal it's likely to produce x-rays.